# Different Layouts with same weights gets different size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layout-weight

In my layout I have two different LinearLayouts. The first one is this:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/lblPais" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/lblJ" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/lblG" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/lblP" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/lblPF" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/lblPC" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/lblDif" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/lblPuntos" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

And the second one is this layout:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="15" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblPais1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/lblPais" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblJ1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/lbl0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblG1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/lbl0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblP1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/lbl0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblPF1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/lbl0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblPC"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/lbl0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblDif1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/lblPtsVacio" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblPuntos1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/lblPtsVacio" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

As you can see both layouts get the same value for the `layout_width` attribute (`match_parent`). Inside both layouts I have the same number of elements (8 TextView). Each TextView has the same weight except the first one, that has a weight of 8.

If both layouts are the same (only differ the label on the TextViews) why do they have different sizes?

Comment: u hv given second layout android:weightSum=15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/lblPais" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/lblJ" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/lblG" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/lblP" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/lblPF" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/lblPC" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/lblDif" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/lblPuntos" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblPais1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/lblPais" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblJ1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/lbl0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblG1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/lbl0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblP1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/lbl0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblPF1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/lbl0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblPC"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/lbl0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblDif1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/lblPtsVacio" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblPuntos1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/lblPtsVacio" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Putting the widht of all the TextViews to 0dip (as Eclipse says that is better to use that rather than 0dp) solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

if you want all layout to be same as your `weight`

your `orientation` is vertical so change...

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

to

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

In all `TextView`

Comment: The ones that have to be 0dp are the `android:layout_width` not the `android:layout_height`

Comment: yup if you set `android:orientation="horizontal"` then set `android:layout_width="0dp"` otherwise `android:layout_height="0dp"`

Answer (score 1):

You havent given `android:weightSum="15"` in first linear layout.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `andoid:weightSum="15"` on the first parent layout and everything should fall into place.

Answer (score 0):

Make your parent linear layout height as 
`android:layout_height="match_parent"`

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is so short. Would you mind expanding it by adding some text to explain how it solves the problem?